# How to specify return value based on if element is found in list?

Tags: list, erlang

I have a list of tuples looking e.g. like this:

```
[{apple, fruit},{pear, fruit},{tomato, vegetable}]
```

One of my functions is supposed to go through the list and return an element by key like this:

```
1> db:find(pear, Db).
{ok,fruit}
```

My function does this and looks like this:

```
find(Key, DbRef) -> [{ok, Element} || {Key1, Element} <- DbRef, Key =:= Key1].
```

But I also want it to return something like this:

```
2> db:find(cucumber, Db).
{error,unknown}
```

when the Key is not found in the list.

Is this possible??

Comment: Use lists:keyfind/3. If the key is not found it returns false, otherwise it returns the complete tuple. Using your examples: ```{pear, fruit} = lists:keyfind(pear, 1, DB)``` when it's found and ```false = lists:keyfind(cucumber, 1, DB``` when it's not. I strongly recommend lists:keyfind because it is a BIF that's implemented in C, and will be noticeably faster than any pure-erlang implementation like yours or the proplists module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to recursively step down the list looking at each element. If it has the right key then you return the value otherwise you call yourself recursively to look at the rest of the list. If you reach the end then you know that the element is not there and you return the `{error,instance}`.

Comment: It would be better to point him to lists:keyfind/3 instead of aiding him in re-implementing the proplists module, but your answer is technically correct.

Comment: @Soupd'Campbells The idea is to not use `lists` but to do it yourself.

Answer (score 6):

Use `lists:keyfind/3` or `proplists:get_value/2,3`.

`lists:keyfind/3` is the ***very best*** option for this task. It is a BIF and, as such, is written in C. It is far and away faster than the `proplists` module or any other pure-erlang implementation. It's also capable of working with more complex tuples with keys in different positions (as would be the case if you had a list of records).

### Examples

Using the `lists` module:

```
{pear, fruit} = lists:keyfind(pear, 1, Db),
false = lists:keyfind(cucumber, 1, Db).
```

Using the `proplists` module:

```
fruit = proplists:get_value(pear, Db),
undefined = proplists:get_value(cucumber, Db),
{error, instance} = proplists:get_value(cucumber, Db, {error, instance}).
```

Or even mix the two, with the `proplists`-style `keyfind`:

```
get_value(Key, List) -> get_value(Key, List, undefined).
get_value(Key, List, Default) ->
    case lists:keyfind(Key, 1, List) of
        false -> Default;
        {Key, Value} -> Value
    end.
```

Usage:

```
fruit = get_value(pear, Db),
undefined = get_value(cucumber, Db),
{error, instance} = get_value(cucumber, Db, {error, instance}).
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds simple:

```
db:find(Key,Proplist)->
    case proplists:get_value(Key,Proplist) of
        undefined -> {error,unknown};
        Value -> {ok,Value}
    end.
```